# Is using windows.h a good thing?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm just curious about whether using windows.h a good thing (PS : I don't care about OSindependent code) ,it seems really good with thousands of functions . So is it good   ? and where is its Dir ?

Comment: Like any other header, you use it if you want the functionality it provides. So if you want windows functionality, it seems pretty good at that.

Comment: Monolithic headers are never good. The more recursive include directives and symbols, the longer the build time.

Comment: @StoryTeller what does monolithic actually mean ?

Comment: @MekacherAnis In the words of Donald Trump, VERY YUGE

Comment: In the realm of software engineering, huge pieces of code that contain EVERYTHING, and are used EVERYWHERE

Comment: Isn't this kind of like asking "is using a screwdriver a good thing?"

Comment: @StoryTeller: With precompiled header files, this is usually not an issue.

Comment: @IInspectable, precompiled headers are no excuse to forego decent dependency management

Comment: No.  It's a horrible, terrible, abominable thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good, bad or indifferent depends on the view.

If you are programming Windows-specific applicaitons, then you'll probably not be able to avoid using it. For generic applications that work on any platform, it's obviously bad, and if you DON'T know that you need some headerfile, don't include it. But do include things that you do need, even if it "works" without - you never know when something changes that header file that dragged in something else you didn't include in your code, and breaks the code.

"Where is it's dir", I presume means "what directory will I find it in", and I'm afraid that's not something I, or anyone else, can tell you. It depends on which compiler you are using, and how/where it was installed - and in some cases, you need to install it separately, in other cases it's included with the compiler. Since there are at least half a dozen different current compilers that work under Windows, and several that no longer are being maintained, but still "works" [to varying degrees], it would be rather pointless to even try to answer this.

Microsoft does publish an "SDK", which contains the headers, should they not be part of your installation of the compiler:
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk